# how to get event of click of button in canvas -- Android?

Tags: android

Anyone please tell me how to get event of click of button , button in canvas  --- Android ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use onclickListener according to what i understood from your question.

Eg; Button button = (Button)findViewById(your button id);

button.setOnClickListener(this);

implement onClickListener.

Add the methods,then do the codings for what you want to do.

Comment: Hy thanks for your quick reply.. but i am using canvas and i use canvas.drawbitmap(..) method. So if user click  on this button in canvas view than which method called and how to set this button click listener ?  if any difference if i used this in canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

To capture the event of when a user clicks a button, you need to call `setOnItemClickListener` for that button, and define the `onClickListener` usually within that method.